# How do I use "OLD" or "NEW" in a dynamic SQL statement in an on-update trigger?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Assuming I have the following function being executed on a row-update:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION versioned_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
     sql TEXT;
BEGIN
    sql := 'INSERT INTO backup_table VALUES (OLD)';
    EXECUTE sql;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

The above example does not work because `OLD` is unknown in that execution context. So I tried something like:

```
sql := format('INSERT INTO backup_table VALUES (%L)', OLD);
```

and

```
sql := format('INSERT INTO backup_table VALUES (%L)', (OLD));
```

and

```
sql := format('INSERT INTO backup_table VALUES (%L)', (OLD.*));
```

All without any luck.

This issue is part of a larger trigger I am working on. Looked in isolation it does not make much sense, but illustrates the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I've finally figured it out. The trick was the notation for [composite data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/rowtypes.html) (and more importantly [their usage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE)) which eventually led me to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION versioned_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
     sql TEXT;
BEGIN
    sql := 'INSERT INTO backup_table VALUES $1.*';
    EXECUTE sql USING OLD;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: What version of postgres were you using? Strangely enough I was unable to get the exact same scenario to work (in V13) without using `VALUES ($1.*)`.

Comment: This must have been either 9.5 or 10. It's been a while so I can't really tell for sure anymore.